# Is "oftener" obsolete?

Tags: word-usage, adverbs, comparatives, literary-english, contemporary-english

Does any native speaker of the English Language ever use *oftener* instead of *more often*?

Comment: It's definitely [gone out of fashion](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=oftener&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=17&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Coftener%3B%2Cc0). Not a word I'd be likely to use - or ever did, so far as I recall, but it's perfectly "credible", so I might have.

Comment: @FumbleFingers I can’t say whether nobody *says* it, but it isn’t written very much any longer even though it once dominated. I’d be unsurprised if certain pockets of the British Isles, or perhaps rustic Appalachia, still preserved the elder usage.

Comment: I would not say that I use it oftener than in the past.  But every now and then it's the word that fits best and is least awkward.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Why yes: Charles Darwin, for one. Or rather, he says *oftenest* as the superlative.  The OED gives this under its entry for **often** *adverb*:

> ### *Comparative and Superlative.*
>
> - 1467 Ordin. Worc. in Eng. Gilds 380 - [They] shullen com and assemble togeder in euery quarter of the yere, ones or oftener and it nede.
> - 1558 Bp. Watson Sev. Sacram. xi. 61 - He..that the oftneste and with moste reuerence commeth.
> - 1660 Boyle Seraph. Love xvi. (1700) 99 - He is rather welcom’st to God that comes to him oftenest, and stays with him longest.
> - A. 1715 Burnet Own Time (1766) I. 246 - As has happened oftner than once before.
> - 1784 Cowper Task i. 411 - An idol at whose shrine Who oft’nest sacrifice are favour’d least.
> - 1866 Darwin Orig. Spec. (ed. 4) iv. 104 - Those individual flowers..would be oftenest visited by insects, and would be oftenest crossed.

However, with regard to *oftentimes*, the extended form of *ofttimes*, the OED notes that the comparative and superlative forms *oftener times* and *oftenest times* are now obsolete, last having been seen before the *Mayflower* cross the Atlantic.

The changeover point was back around the *fin de siècle*, and not the most recent thereof, either, as shown by [this Google N-Gram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=oftener%2Cmore+often&year_start=1800&year_end=2008&corpus=0&smoothing=0&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Coftener%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cmore%20often%3B%2Cc0):

[image: Ngram of oftener and more often]

That being said, I myself would use *more often* and *most often* as the comparative and superlative degrees of *often*. In the popularity contest of Google, the two-word versions do come out far in the lead for [*oftener*](http://googlefight.com/index.php?lang=en_GB&word1=oftener&word2=more+often) and even more so with [*oftenest*](http://googlefight.com/index.php?lang=en_GB&word1=oftenest&word2=most+often).

---

> ### “Out of Sight, Out of Mind”, by [Barnabe Googe](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Barnabe_Googe) [1540–1594]
>
> **The oftener seen**, the more I lust,
>    The more I lust, the more I smart,
>    The more I smart, the more I trust,
>    The more I trust, the heavier heart;
>    The heavy hearty breeds mine unrest,
>    Thy absence, therefore, like I best.
>
> The rarer seen, the lest in mind,
>    The less in mind, the lesser pain,
>    The lesser pain, less grief I find,
>    The lesser grief, the greater gain,
>    The greater gain, the merrier I,
>    Therefore I wish thy sight to fly.
>
> The further off, the more I joy,
>    The more I joy, the happier life,
>    The happier life, less hurts annoy,
>    The lesser hurts, pleasure most rife:
>    Such pleasures rife shall I obtain
>    When distance doth depart us twain.

Comment: While one has to interpret such graphs with caution, in this case, it does seem to tell quite a clear story! I assume the spikes at the very end of the graph are just artefacts...

Comment: @NeilCoffey That would be my guess, yes. The simpler *oft* isn’t used very much any longer, but its comparative degree survived more than two centuries longer than its superlative degree, per the OED.  Its comparative *ofter* is labelled “archaic and dialectal” but with 19th-century citations, while *oftest* is now marked “obsolete” and last seen in Milton. We see something of the same relative distribution of *oftener* and *oftenest*, where *oftener* seems to have endured a bit more than *oftenest*. But I don’t know for sure that no native speakers anywhere ever use either of them any longer.

Answer (score 1):

When I was thirty-six years old I used the word "oftener" (which was still in very limited usage then) and was promptly interrupted by my five year old daughter with "dad it's 'often' not 'oftener'. I have never used the Apalachian form since and I am now 79

Answer (score 1):

I just noted, in my 1966 U.S. government Selective Service form, the following phrase - "this form is to be prepared annually, or oftener as appropriate..."